# How to add all items in a String array to a vector in Java?

Tags: java, string, arrays, vector, addition

My code looks like this :

```
Vector<String> My_Vector=new Vector<String>();
String My_Array[]=new String[100];

for (int i=0;i<100;i++) My_Array[i]="Item_"+i;
......
My_Vector.addAll(My_Array);
```

But I got an error message, what's the right way to do it, without looping to add each item ?

Frank

Comment: Why are you using Vector?  I'd prefer an ArrayList, because it's not synchronized by default.

Comment: Don't use Vector, it is a legacy class, use ArrayList instead.

And just use `My_Vector.add("Item_"+i);` instead of using a intermediate array

Comment: Wow.  I haven't seen a Vector pulled out in at least 5 years. :)  Brings me back to JDK 1.1.  You probably want to go with Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList()).

Comment: for vector and arrays of objects : `Vector<Object> rows = new Vector<Object>();` `Object[] labels = new Object[columnCount];` following methods works : `rows.add(labels);`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The vector.addAll()takes a Collection in parameter.
In order to convert array to Collection, you can use Arrays.asList():

```
My_Vector.addAll(Arrays.asList(My_Array));
```

Comment: Chris Jester-Young answer (currently the top-voted) provides a better alternative.

Answer (score 61):

```
Collections.addAll(myVector, myArray);
```

This is the preferred way to add the contents of an array into a collection (such as a vector).

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#addAll-java.util.Collection-T...-

> Adds all of the specified elements to the specified collection.
>   Elements to be added may be specified individually or as an array. The
>   behavior of this convenience method is identical to that of
>   c.addAll(Arrays.asList(elements)), but this method is likely to run
>   significantly faster under most implementations.

Comment: +1 for correcting my typo, and providing this "significantly faster" alternative.

Comment: The implementation of that method will loop: `for (T element : elements)`.

Comment: You are indeed correct, but you didn't say why it is is preferred.  The Javadoc says: the behavior of this convenience method is identical to that of c.addAll(Arrays.asList(elements)), but this method is likely to run significantly faster under most implementations.

Comment: @Dean: You are correct (that I didn't say why it was preferred): I was going for a "Fastest Gun in the West" answer, but indeed, the added performance is why it's preferred.

Answer (score 7):

```
My_Vector.addAll(Arrays.asList(My_Array));
```

If you notice, [`Collection.addAll`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%29) takes a `Collection` argument. A Java array is not a `Collection`, but [`Arrays.asList`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29), in combination with [`Collection.toArray`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#toArray%28%29), is the "bridge between array-based and collection-based APIs".

Alternatively, for the specific purpose of adding elements from an array to a `Collection`, you can also use the static helper method [`addAll`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection,%20T...%29) from the `Collections` class.

```
Collections.addAll(My_Vector, My_Array);
```